# Поиск блока по тексту заголовка (jQuery, javascript, html, css)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, поиск, выборка

Есть блок карточек со строкой поиска:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="searchValue" name="valueId"/>
    <input type="button" id="searchBtn" />
</form>
<div class='row'>
   <div class='card'>
      <div class='card-title'>TitleOne</div>
   </div>
   <div class='card'>
      <div class='card-title'>TitleTwo</div>
   </div>
</div
```

Нужно сделать поиск по введенному слову и вывести только те блоки, у которых card-title.text() совпадает с введенным значением в input.
Получаю значение input'a вот так, а потом завис. Подскажите, что дальше?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#searchBtn').click(function () {
                    let text = $('.card-title').text();
                    let value = $('#searchValue').val();
                    if (text.includes(value)) { // Фильтр какой-то должен быть здесь
                        console.log(text)
                    }                    
                });                               
            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#searchBtn').click(function () {
  let value = $('#searchValue').val();
  $('.card-title').each(function() {
    let card = $(this).closest('.card');
    let text = $(this).text();
    text.includes(value)? card.show() : card.hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Сначала не работало, потом поменял 1-ю и 2-ю строку местами и всё пошло-поехало :)